capturing an image using media foundation
I have an issue working with Windows API and the Media Foundation library. The code I have below captures and saves an image from the webcam, but the resulting image is in black and white, and there are two images side by side. Can anyone help me with this?
#include <windows.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#include <mfobjects.h>
#include <mferror.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfreadwrite.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mf.lib")

const GUID MFVideoFormat_RGB32 = { 0x00000016, 0x0000, 0x0010, {0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0xaa, 0x00, 0x38, 0x9b, 0x71} };
const GUID MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE = { 0x48eba18e, 0xf8c9, 0x4687, {0xbf, 0x11, 0x0a, 0x74, 0xc9, 0xf9, 0x6a, 0x8f} };
const GUID MF_MT_SUBTYPE = { 0xf7e34c9a, 0x42e8, 0x4714, {0xb7, 0x83, 0x5e, 0xbd, 0xa4, 0x3a, 0xe5, 0x04} };
const GUID MFMediaType_Video = { 0x73646976, 0x0000, 0x0010, {0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0xaa, 0x00, 0x38, 0x9b, 0x71} };

HRESULT InitializeMediaFoundation() {
    HRESULT hr = MFStartup(MF_VERSION);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        printf("MFStartup failed: 0x%lx\n", hr);
    }
    return hr;
}

HRESULT CreateVideoDeviceSource(IMFMediaSource** ppSource) {
    IMFAttributes* pAttributes = NULL;
    IMFActivate** ppDevices = NULL;
    UINT32 count = 0;
    HRESULT hr = MFCreateAttributes(&pAttributes, 1);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        printf("MFCreateAttributes failed: 0x%lx\n", hr);
        return hr;
    }

    hr = pAttributes->SetGUID(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE, MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_GUID);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        printf("SetGUID MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE failed: 0x%lx\n", hr);
        pAttributes->Release();
        return hr;
    }

    hr = MFEnumDeviceSources(pAttributes, &ppDevices, &count);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        printf("MFEnumDeviceSources failed: 0x%lx\n", hr);
        pAttributes->Release();
        return hr;
    }

    if (count > 0) {
        hr = ppDevices[0]->ActivateObject(IID_PPV_ARGS(ppSource));
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            printf("ActivateObject failed: 0x%lx\n", hr);
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("No video capture devices found.\n");
        hr = E_FAIL;
    }

    for (UINT32 i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ppDevices[i]->Release();
    }
    CoTaskMemFree(ppDevices);
    pAttributes->Release();

    return hr;
}
HRESULT CaptureImage() {
    IMFMediaSource* pSource = NULL;
    IMFSourceReader* pReader = NULL;
    IMFMediaType* pType = NULL;
    DWORD streamIndex = MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM;
    HRESULT hr = CreateVideoDeviceSource(&pSource);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }

    hr = MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource(pSource, NULL, &pReader);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        printf("MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource failed: 0x%lx\n", hr);
        pSource->Release();
        return hr;
    }

    hr = pReader->GetCurrentMediaType(streamIndex, &pType);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        printf("GetCurrentMediaType failed: 0x%lx\n", hr);
        pReader->Release();
        pSource->Release();
        return hr;
    }

    hr = pType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_RGB32);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        printf("SetGUID MF_MT_SUBTYPE failed: 0x%lx\n", hr);
        pType->Release();
        pReader->Release();
        pSource->Release();
        return hr;
    }

    hr = pReader->SetCurrentMediaType(streamIndex, NULL, pType);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        printf("SetCurrentMediaType failed: 0x%lx\n", hr);
        pType->Release();
        pReader->Release();
        pSource->Release();
        return hr;
    }

    pType->Release();

    IMFSample* pSample = NULL;
    DWORD dwFlags = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        hr = pReader->ReadSample(streamIndex, 0, NULL, &dwFlags, NULL, &pSample);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pSample) {
            break;  
        }
        Sleep(100); 
    }

    if (FAILED(hr) || !pSample) {
        printf("ReadSample failed: 0x%lx\n", hr);
        printf("Flags: 0x%lx\n", dwFlags); flags
        pReader->Release();
        pSource->Release();
        return hr;
    }

    printf("Sample read successfully.\n");
    IMFMediaBuffer* pBuffer = NULL;
    hr = pSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&pBuffer);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        printf("ConvertToContiguousBuffer failed: 0x%lx\n", hr);
        pSample->Release();
        pReader->Release();
        pSource->Release();
        return hr;
    }

    BYTE* pData = NULL;
    DWORD cbBuffer = 0;
    hr = pBuffer->Lock(&pData, NULL, &cbBuffer);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        printf("Lock failed: 0x%lx\n", hr);
        pBuffer->Release();
        pSample->Release();
        pReader->Release();
        pSource->Release();
        return hr;
    }

    const char* filePath = "C:\\capture.bmp";
    FILE* pFile;
    fopen_s(&pFile, filePath, "wb");
    if (pFile) {
        BITMAPFILEHEADER bfHeader;
        BITMAPINFOHEADER biHeader;

        bfHeader.bfType = 'MB';
        bfHeader.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + cbBuffer;
        bfHeader.bfReserved1 = 0;
        bfHeader.bfReserved2 = 0;
        bfHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

        biHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        biHeader.biWidth = 640;
        biHeader.biHeight = -480;
        biHeader.biPlanes = 1;
        biHeader.biBitCount = 32;
        biHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
        biHeader.biSizeImage = cbBuffer;
        biHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
        biHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
        biHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
        biHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

        fwrite(&bfHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, pFile);
        fwrite(&biHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, pFile);
        fwrite(pData, cbBuffer, 1, pFile);
        fclose(pFile);

        printf("Image saved to %s\n", filePath);
    }
    else {
        printf("Failed to open file for writing\n");
    }

    hr = pBuffer->Unlock();
    pBuffer->Release();

    if (pSample) {
        pSample->Release();
    }
    if (pReader) {
        pReader->Release();
    }
    if (pSource) {
        pSource->Release();
    }

    return hr;
}


int main() {
    HRESULT hr = InitializeMediaFoundation();
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = CaptureImage();
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            printf("Image captured successfully.\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Failed to capture image: 0x%lx\n", hr);
        }
    }
    MFShutdown();
    return 0;
}

here is one sample image

I am using Visual Studio 2022. This is a program that captures an image from the webcam and saves it to the C drive.

Can you clarify what your issues is? What debugging details can you provide? One thing I find strange is that you have to declare the values for the GUID's yourself.

To can use ComPtr and forget all those->Release() before return .

The reason I declare the GUID values myself was that the IDE gave errors and couldn't find them, even though I included the header file mfapi.h.

Changing just MF_MT_SUBTYPE you don't have a sane media type.

SetCurrentMediaType seems to work because MF_MT_SUBTYPE value is wrong, should be {0xf7e34c9a,0x42e8,0x4714,{0xb7,0x4b,0xcb,0x29,0xd7,0x2c,0x35,0xe5}}. If you use the good value, SetCurrentMediaType will return an error (like MF_E_INVALIDMEDIATYPE). You should instead query for MF_MT_SUBTYPE to determine the type. For example my camera outputs MEDIASUBTYPE_YUY2. Then, you'll have to convert it if you want RGB, for example using the Color Converter DSP https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/colorconverter
